# Rearrange linked list in python

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to solve the question on Cracking the Code Interview by using Python.

Question:
For example, suppose you had a linked list a1->a2->•••->an->b1->b2 ->••• ->bn and you wanted to
rearrange it into a1->b1 ->a2->b2-> •••->an->bn. You do not know the length of the linked list (but you
do know that a length is an even number).

But it turns out my code falls into an infinite loop after rearranging.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, elem, next=None):
        self.elem = elem
        self.next = next

class SingleLinkList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None 
        self.next = None
    def is_empty(self): 
        return self.head == None
    def append(self,item):         
        node = Node(item)
        if self.is_empty():
            self.head = node
            node.next=None
        else:
            cur = self.head
            while cur.next != None:
                cur=cur.next
            cur.next = node
            node.next = None
    def linked_list_rearrange(self):
        fast = self.head
        slow = self.head
        while fast != None:
            fast = fast.next.next 
            slow = slow.next
        fast = self.head
        while slow != None:
            temp = slow.next
            #print(temp.elem)
            slow.next = fast.next
            fast.next = slow
            fast = slow.next
            slow = temp
tlist=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
ll=SingleLinkList()
for i in tlist:
    ll.append(i)
ll.linked_list_rearrange()
cur = ll.head
while cur!= None:
    print(cur.elem,end=" ")
    cur = cur.next
```

But when I forced to stop the loop by taking the first 10 nodes, it seems the data looks right.

```
while cur!= None:
    print(cur.elem,end=" ")
    if cur.elem == 9:
        break
    else:
        cur = cur.next
```

Result:[ResultN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adp8M.png)

I have no idea why my code is wrong. Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

In your second while loop, when `slow` is on the last node, it is connected to `fast` and receives the next pointer of that `fast` node which still connects to the middle node of the list.  This places a next link on `slow` which creates a circular reference in the list.

To avoid this, you could either change the condition of the second while (to check when fast reaches your initial slow) or break the next link of the node preceding your initial `slow` node before that second while loop.